# Getting java null pointer exception when adding object class to reportGroup.getReportList()

Tags: java

I have assigned the values to the member of a Report Info class and tried to add to the Report Group class.Getting java null pointer exception.Even though I have already initialized report Info at the very beginning.

Getting  error when doing this- reportGroup.getReportList().add(reportInfo);

I have two java classes.

```
 ReportGroup.java
    String GroupName;
    List<ReportInfo>reportList; 

    public String getReportGroupName() {
    return ReportGroupName;
}
public void setReportGroupName(String reportGroupName) {
    ReportGroupName = reportGroupName;
}
public List<ReportInfo> getReportList() {
    return reportList;
}
public void setReportList(List<ReportInfo> reportList) {
    this.reportList = reportList;
}

}

ReportInfo.java
    String ReportName;
    String ReportId;
    String ReportPath;
    //Getter and Setter
```

Main class:

```
public class test {
 List<ReportInfo> reportInfo = new ArrayList<ReportInfo>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String orgId="346";
    String orgName="Ralph Lauren Corporation";

    String reportPath= "/"+orgId +"_"+orgName.replaceAll(" ","_");
    String reportFolderPath = "C:/Lokesh/Dev Tools/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/webapps/ROOT/Reports";
    List<String> filesArray = null;
    filesArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    String filetowrite="C:/Users/lbandhu/Desktop/test.html";
    FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(filetowrite);

    ReportGroup reportGroup=new ReportGroup();
    reportGroup.setReportGroupName(orgName); //Organization Name such as Ralph Lauren Corporation

    fw.write("<html><head><title>"+ reportGroup.ReportGroupName+"</title><h1>Utilization Report</h1><span>Please contact your account manager for a listing of utilization report definitions or with any questions on your organization’s reports. </span><br></head><body><table>");
    //fw.write("<br><h>"+orgName+"</h><br>");


    File folder = new File(reportFolderPath+reportPath);

    List<String> reportNames =  listFolder(folder);


    for (String rname : reportNames) {
        ReportInfo reportInfo=new ReportInfo();
        reportInfo.setReportName(rname);

        folder = new File(reportFolderPath+reportPath+"/"+reportInfo.ReportName);
        System.out.println(folder);
        fw.write("<br><tr> "+reportInfo.ReportName +" Utilization Reports</tr><br>"); //Report Name such as Monthly,Quarterly and Yearly
        Iterator<String> iterator=listFilesForFolder(folder, filesArray).iterator();
        writeReportPath( fw,iterator, reportFolderPath,reportInfo);
        fw.write("<br>");
        reportGroup.getReportList().add(reportInfo); 
    }
    filesArray.clear();
    fw.close();

}
```

Comment: reportList seams to be not initialized like 'List<ReportInfo>reportList = new ArrayList<ReportInfo>();'

Comment: It's initialized at the very top!!

Comment: I don't see that! You are initializing ReportGroup

Comment: Right before the main method starts.  List<ReportInfo> reportInfo = new ArrayList<ReportInfo>();

Comment: reportInfo and not reportList

Comment: report-list is not an object class which needs to be Initialized.It's the member of reportGroup class.

Comment: There are 2 object class and I have initialized both!!

Comment: It is a list (= an object), and til now it equals to null

Comment: Could you please post the constructor for ReportGroup?

Comment: the method 'getReportList()' return null, then getReportList().add(..) will trigger the null pointer exception

Comment: @Burnt I have updated my code with constructors for ReportGroup

Comment: @Riadh  I think it's my question!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initializing the field `reportInfo` of instances of your `test` class, but not the field `reportInfo` of your `ReportGroup`s.  It doesn't look like you actually instanciate your `test` class, and this field is not visible to static (i. e. class) methods anyway.  Even if it were visible (for example, if it were static itself), you would shadow it with the local variable `reportInfo`.

When you do `ReportInfo reportInfo = new ReportInfo()` in the first line of your `for` loop, you are creating a new `ReportGroup` with a new `reportInfo` member, which is uninitialized.

Your `ReportGroup` should look about like this:

```
class ReportGroup {
    final List<ReportInfo> reportInfo = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Alternatively, you can do the initialization in the constructor:

```
class ReportGroup {
    final List<ReportInfo> reportInfo;

    ReportGroup () {
        reportInfo = new ArrayList<ReportInfo>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize the list in the constructor:

```
 public ReportGroup(){
     reportList  = new ArrayList<ReportInfo>();
 }
```

or

```
 public ReportGroup(String GroupName){
     this.GroupName = GroupName;
     reportList  = new ArrayList<ReportInfo>();
 }
```

Comment: Isn't the same thing as above,can initialize either way which I already have at the very top.

Comment: in your current code, replace 'List<ReportInfo> reportInfo;' by 'List<ReportInfo> reportInfo = new ArrayList<ReportInfo>();', and test again please

Comment: @Thanks Riadh, I know what you mean now

Comment: you are welcome! we should thank the stackoverflow community also